# Entityframework codefirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. Создал консольное приложение. С использованием code first. Скопировал из базы данных data source:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\MyDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Создал модельки, сделал миграции. Решил найти как сделать путь в строке универсальным. Что бы проект не был привязан к определённому месту. Нашёл вот такой вот вариант, а точнее просто в windows forms добавил на форму гриду, и начал в неё добавлять дата сет, и он сам сгенерил вот такую вот строчку, а я её оттуда скопировал:

```
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Делаю миграцию, делаю апдейт базы, но не тут то было. С такой строкой подключения таблица не обновляется. Что я делаю не так подскажите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал с этой строкой подключения.

Comment: Вот это `|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf` указывает на какую БД? На какой конкретно файл?

Comment: @tym32167 На ту что лежит в этом проекте.

Comment: Вы в этом точно уверены? Может вы обновляете БД в папке Bin/Debug, а проверяете обновление в БД в проекте?

Comment: @tym32167 видел пример такого же использования connection string на metanit'е только там ещё апострофы были, но с ними тоже пробовал. То есть когда я просто тяну данные с таким коннектион стригом всё норм. Но update миграций не проходит.

Comment: @tym32167 а как это проверить? Не задумывался об этом.

Comment: Это мне ни о чем не говорит. Ищите у себя к какой конкретно БД подключаетесь, так как есть подозрение, что вы меняете одну БД, а ждете изменений в другой. Я такое уже видел, такое часто тут случается.

Comment: @tym32167 в modify connection у самой базы путь `D:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\MyDb.mdf` то есть это та самая база в проекте. А как я могу обновлять базу в бине? Что именно я делаю не так?

Comment: Задайте абсолютный путь как в первом случае и проверьте, если все заработает, то ищите копии свой БД в Bin/Debug или где то среди проекта

Comment: @tym32167 копию базы в дебаге я уже нашёл, так а делаю то я что не так? Коннектион стринг у меня не верный или что? На метаните такой пример. Я немного не могу вас понять. Саму копию базы я нашёл. Сейчас у меня универсальный путь, такой который я вторым показал.

Comment: @tym32167 она там создаётся после каждого запуска проекта.

Comment: Хорошо, вы нашли копию БД в Bin/Debug. Теперь загляните внутрь базы, там есть ваши миграции, что вы ищете? Про метанит мне бесполезно писать, я не в курсе, что это

Comment: @tym32167 да есть, вы правы, так как теперь сделать так что при таком вот универсальном пути апдейтилась нужная база?

Comment: Нужная база - понятие широкое. Если ваша текущая универсальная строка указывает не туда, куда надо, меняйте строку соединения, указывайте полный путь до файла БД. Хотя с моей точки зрения нужная база лежит как раз в bin/debug, а среди исходников базе вообще делать нечего

Comment: @tym32167 понятно, спасибо за подсказку.